# Error handling - Wrong URL in Jquery AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to handle wrong/doesn't exist URL (http://localhost/abcd) in jquery Ajax. I am using jQuery 1.10.2. The response is :

```
{
    "error": {
        "message": "Page Not Found.",
        "status_code": "404"
    }
}

Status code is 404 and I can see it in Postman.
```

I have tried the following code to give me an alert. Debugger doesn't come in error block only.

```
error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

            if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
                alert ('Not connected.\nPlease verify your network connection.');
            } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
                alert ('The requested page not found. [404]');
            } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
                alert ('Internal Server Error [500].');
            } else if (errorThrown === 'parsererror') {
                alert ('Requested JSON parse failed.');
            } else if (errorThrown === 'timeout') {
                alert ('Time out error.');
            } else if (errorThrown === 'abort') {
                alert ('Ajax request aborted.');
            } else {
                alert ('Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText);
            }
}
```

Comment: no luck? give more detail. What do you want? An alert/redirect?

Comment: Could you give us the headers returned by the server ? I think you have a custom 404 page that returns the status 200 not 404.

Comment: return not working for you case change return with alert

Comment: You missed the status code102. Its is the code returned for ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED situations.

Comment: What exactly doesn't work?

Comment: I have updated the question and tried to answer all your questions.

Comment: Alert works. I am not getting 404 error.

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be using (===) in the conditions, try with (==).

Hope helps